# Polymer dropdown data binding with AJAX response

Tags: javascript, ajax, data-binding, polymer

I'm very new to JS and Polymer. Can't figure out why this is not working, I've rewritten it a millin times based on the few topics out there.

The idea is to have a very simple dropdown with it's choices data bound to the response of the AJAX request.

Based on the logging the AJAX is returning perfectly, but the data is not bound.

Can anyone help please?

**The AJAX response:**

```
var text = '{ "employees" : [' +
            '{ "firstName":"John" , "lastName":"Doe" },' +
            '{ "firstName":"Anna" , "lastName":"Smith" },' +
            '{ "firstName":"Peter" , "lastName":"Jones" } ]}';
```

**Scripts and imports** (probably more than it should be, I was experimenting with components)

```
<script src="../../static/bower/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js"></script>
<script src="../../static/npm/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="../../static/npm/webanimations/web-animations.min.js"></script>    

<link rel="import" href="../../static/bower/font-roboto/roboto.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../static/bower/core-header-panel/core-header-panel.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../static/bower/core-toolbar/core-toolbar.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../static/bower/paper-tabs/paper-tabs.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../static/bower/paper-dropdown-menu/paper-dropdown-menu.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../static/bower/core-ajax/core-ajax.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../static/bower/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../static/bower/core-list/core-list.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../static/bower/core-collapse/core-collapse.html" >
<link rel="import" href="../../static/bower/core-menu/core-menu.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../static/bower/paper-dropdown/paper-dropdown.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../static/bower/paper-item/paper-item.html">
```

**HTML**

```
<body>

<polymer-element name="custom-selector" attributes="host data">
    <template>
        <template if="{{data.length == 0}}">
            <core-ajax auto 
                url="dosql" 
                on-core-response="{{updateData}}" 
                on-core-error="{{onError}}"
                response="{{yourData}}"
            </core-ajax>
        </template>
        <paper-dropdown-menu label="Dropdown with Data" on-core-select="{{selectData}}">
            <paper-dropdown class="dropdown">
            <core-menu class="menu">
                <template repeat="{{data in yourData}}">
                        <paper-item name="{{data.firstName}}">{{data.firstName}}</paper-item>
                </template>
            </core-menu>
            </paper-dropdown>
        </paper-dropdown-menu>
    </template>

    <script>
        Polymer('custom-selector', {
            ready: function () { console.log('firing ready');
                this.host = this.host || 'example.com'; 
                this.data = this.data || []; 
            },
            onError: function (e, resp) { console.log('onError');
                console.log('error!: ' + resp.response);
            },
            updateData: function (e, resp) { console.log('firing updateData');
                console.log('AJAX response:');
                console.log(JSON.parse(resp.response));
                this.data = JSON.parse(resp.response);

                console.log('this.data is now:');
                console.log(this.data);
            }
        });
    </script>
</polymer-element>



<custom-selector></custom-selector>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<template repeat="{{data in yourData}}">
```

`yourData` is not an array, it is an object. What you are trying to achieve is this:

```
<template repeat="{{data in yourData.employees}}">
```

I took the liberty of improving your element a bit. I hope you can learn from this, if you need further explanation feel free to ask.

```
<polymer-element name="custom-selector" attributes="host data">
<template>
    <core-ajax 
        id="employeesgetter"
        handleAs="json"
        url="dosql" 
        on-core-error="{{onError}}"
        response="{{data}}">
    </core-ajax>
    <paper-dropdown-menu label="Dropdown with Data" on-core-select="{{selectData}}">
        <paper-dropdown class="dropdown">
            <core-menu class="menu">
                <template repeat="{{employee in data.employees}}">
                    <paper-item name="{{employee.firstName}}">{{employee.firstName}}</paper-item>
                </template>
            </core-menu>
        </paper-dropdown>
    </paper-dropdown-menu>
</template>

<script>
    Polymer('custom-selector', {
        data: {
            employees: []
        },
        ready: function () { 
            console.log('firing ready');
            this.host = this.host || 'example.com'; 
            this.$.employeesgetter.go();
        },
        onError: function (e, resp) { 
            console.log('onError');
            console.log('error!: ' + resp.response);
        }
    });
</script>
</polymer-element>
```

Comment: Thanks for this - you are right. After making the change the dropdown is still empty, no error message.

Comment: Hi, can you try it with the element I posted and report back the results?

Comment: It's beautiful, and yes, very educational :) No error message, but the dropdown is empty. Would you mind taking a look at my imports?

Comment: Add `handleAs="json"` to your core-ajax. I have updated my code

Comment: :) This will go a very long way - now I can basically develop apps ;) THANK YOU!!!